# How to create a good PATCH endpoint when some properties can change and some can't based on the status of the resource?

Tags: rest

Consider I have the following Resource:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Text {get; set;}

    public int ReminderInDays {get; set;}

    // Determined by resource itself
    public FooStatus Status {get;set;}
}
```

Now, let's say we want to be able to update these. Normally, you could create a PATCH endpoint:

`PATCH api/foos/1` with a body that contains both `Text` and `ReminderInDays`. (I do not use stuff like Jsonpatch where you can submit only the changed properties).

This would work fine. But how about the following scenario:

- `Text` can change when Status is `New` and `Submitted`
- `ReminderInDays` can change when Status is `New`

If I were to use my PATCH example, I could use a body like the following when status is `New`, and everything would be OK:

```json
{
  "Text": "Hello World!",
  "ReminderInDays": 3
}
```

But if I were to use this when the status of the resource is `Submitted` and I would change `ReminderInDays` to 5, the Resource would throw an error because I am not allowed to change that property anymore. Based on this information, the only way I can think of having 1 endpoint to change both, is to ignore the `ReminderInDays` property when the Resource tells me the property can't be changed.

This seems like an ugly solution to me. You need to submit useless data to the API which is a waste.

Another solution is to have 2 endpoints:

- `PATCH api/foos/1/text`
- `PATCH api/foos/1/reminderInDays`

This isn't really RESTFUL, but would solve my issues.

Does anyone have any other ideas? What is the right thing to do :)?